# Two issues with field validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on my first ASP.NET MVC 3 project. For some of the fields on an edit page I want the user to be able to either choose a value from previously-entered values or enter a new one, so I'm using the jQuery autocomplete to accomplish this.  That part seems to work just fine.  Now, for some fields the user can choose to enter a value or not and if they do enter one, I want to validate it against some rules, so I created my own `ValidationAttribute`.

The validation piece will definitely check the given value against the rules and return the correct boolean value for the `IsValid` call.  Great.

The **first problem** that I'm having is that if my validator's `IsValid` returns false, it displays the error message I've specified but if I enter something which is valid, the `TextBox` clears it's error background color but the error message does not clear.  This happens in either FF or IE8.

The **second problem** is that for FireFox, my autocomplete values will display again when I edit the text in the textbox but in IE 8, once the error condition exists, my autocomplete stops working.  Occasionally, if I enter a value which I know is in the autocomplete list, it will show up but it seems a bit flaky.

I may just be doing this validation thing wrong.  Here's the relevant code I use. I'd be quite interested in any guidance one can give about either of these issues.  The attribute is a test one but it exhibits the behavior on my page.

My ValidationAttribute:

```
public class MyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
   ...

   public override bool IsValid(object value)
   {
      if (value == null)
      {
         return true;
      }
      var stringValue = Convert.ToString(value);
      if (stringValue.Length == 0)
      {
         return true;
      }
      if (stringValue.Trim().Length == 0)
      {
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   }

   ...
```

}

My autocomplete code:

```
$("#toppingid").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AvailableToppings", "IceCream")', type: "POST", dataType: "json",
            data: { query: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item, value: item };
                }))
            }
        })
    },
    minLength: 1
});
```

My controller action:

```
public JsonResult AvailableToppings()
{
    // I actually retrieve this differently, but you get the idea
    List<string> all = new List<string>() { "BerryCrush", "Caramel", "Fudge" };
    return Json(all, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My view snippet:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Topping, new { @id = "toppingid" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Topping)
```

My viewmodel snippet:

```
[DisplayName("Topping:")]
[MyAttribute(ErrorMessage = "Can't be all blanks!")]
public string Topping { get; set; }
```

In my post action, I have logic something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(IceCreamCreateEditViewModel viewModel)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      // stuff happens here which isn't germane

      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   // redisplay the view to the user
   return Create();
}
```

I think that's all the relevant pieces of code.  Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your first question, it looks like the autocomplete plugin removes the `input-validation-error` class from the textbox when a selection is made. Because of this the textbox clears its background. One way to workaround this is to subscribe for the [select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) event and reapply this class if there is an error (by checking whether the error label is displayed):

```
$("#toppingid").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        ...
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var topping = $('#toppingid');
        // find the corresponding error label
        var errorLabel = $('span[data-valmsg-for="' + topping.attr('name') + '"]');
        if (errorLabel.is(':visible')) {
            // if the error label is visible reapply the CSS class 
            // to the textbox
            topping.addClass('input-validation-error');
        }
    },
    minLength: 1
});
```

As far as your second question is concerned, unfortunately I am unable to reproduce it. The autocomplete doesn't stop working in IE8 if there is a validation error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Darin.  Unfortunately your idea isn't working on my page - I get the same behavior as before.  I stepped through the script and it definitely reaches the line `topping.addClass(...` but the error message remains on the page.

Comment: @itsmatt, it's normal that the error message will remain. All that this does is to reapply the red background to the textbox which is lost when you select an item from the autocomplete list and which was your first question. The error message will disappear when you submit the form because validation is performed on the server through your custom attribute.

Comment: so the coloration has been fine all along.  As I mentioned in my question, it's the text that doesn't go away - which behaves differently than in the case of the other validated fields where I display some text and once the user edits it correctly, the error message disappears.  Was hoping to mimic that behavior.  I guess this is due to the fact that the other validation is client-side, right?

Comment: @itsmatt, there is no client side validation for this field. Your custom attribute doesn't implement `IClientValidatable`, so no client validation.